# How to update Google Chrome to latest version by script? Python

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome

I need to update Google Chrome by script in python. It is a part of a task (testing).

At first, I check whether the device is running the latest version of Chrome; if not, update it.

I have written the following script for updating, but it does not work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("chrome://chrome-urls/")
time.sleep(7)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="chrome://help/"]')
element.click()
time.sleep(10)
elementNew = driver.find_element_by_id("relaunch")
time.sleep(15)
if elementNew.is_displayed():
    print("Google Chrome is not up to date")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()

else:
    print("Google Chrome is up to date")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.close()
```

Does anyone know an easier way to perform it?

Or, maybe, a completely different way?